# Pygame has no module named 'math'

Tags: python, pygame

After typing in this:

`from pygame.math import *`

I get an error saying this:

```
ImportError: No module named math
```

It worked perfectly when I tried doing this on Windows, but when I tried it on ubuntu 15.04 it doesn't work and throws the above error.

I have already installed the pygame package using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

and doing `import pygame` works perfectly. I don't know why it doesn't import pygame.math.

Also, I am using Python 2.7.9

Comment: Did you check your pygame installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.math`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) is experimental and

> New in Pygame 1.10

Your version of `pygame` should be 1.9.1.